# How to exclude not applicable values in Tableau calculation

Tags: tableau-api

I'm computing average, my dataset has 99 recorded in not applicable cases, How to exclude those 99 in average computation?

Answer (score 0):

Take a dimension or measure which you can filter on, and use this to exclude the cases.

You can also [use a parameter](https://interworks.com/blog/interworks/2012/03/26/how-to-create-and-use-parameters-in-tableau/) to remove these, or group the values if of one type (e.g. apples).

Alternatively, if your exclusions require a logic scenario you can create a calculated field that you can filter on.

Go to Analysis > Create Calculated field:

```
IF ([FRUIT] = 'APPLES' AND [FRUIT] = 'BANANAS') THEN 1
ELSE IF ([VEGETABLE] = 'CUCUMBER') THEN 1
ELSE 0
END
```

Then just set your filter to 0 or 1 following your logic.